# Eslint --max-warnings to Tslint

Tags: typescript, eslint, tslint

I am tring to add a `lint-staged` rule like `eslint --max-warnings=0` but using `tslint`.
So, the question is is it possible and if so how ? nothing usefull on their doc website.